# Arrow function assigned to variable without variable declaration keyword?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm not very well-acquainted with arrow functions and encountered a usage of them I don't understand. After looking through a few articles on arrow functions, it seems like a variable declaration keyword should precede the variable name. If not, why wouldn't that be the case? (The code works.)

For example why isn't `var`, `let`, or `const` before `getParameterByName`?

```
getParameterByName = (name, url) => {
 ...
}
```

Comment: It's the same as doing `a = 1;`. Declaring a variable without `var`, `let`, or `const` will just declare the variable globally (`window`).

Comment: you can also do this with old function expressions ... `getParameterByName = function (name, url) {
 ...
}` - so there's nothing special about `=>` notation in this case

Comment: Has `getParameterByName` already been declared elsewhere? If not, that's not a good practice, if yes: it's just an assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sloppy-mode JavaScript, assignment to a variable that isn't declared will set that property on the global object. This (as you can tell because this question exists) is confusing behaviour.

In general you should always use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). Many confusing behaviours are fixed in strict mode, including the case you ask about here.

```js
'use strict';

a = () => {};
```

As you can see, running this snippet gives a ReferenceError because `a` is not declared.